# wxpython textctrl How to find out where the text pointer is

Tags: wxpython, textctrl

I need to know where the text pointer (blinking line) is in the textctrl. I would also like to know if it is possible to get the entire line that the pointer is on, or if I would just have to write the code to get the current line from the pointer position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `GetInsertionPoint()` to find the current position of the cursor.  You can use: `len( self.LogWindow.GetRange( 0, self.LogWindow.GetInsertionPoint() ).split("\n") )` to get the line number itself.

And then you can use:
`GetLineText()` to get the entire line of text...

So:

```
curPos = self.LogWindow.GetInsertionPoint
lineNum = self.LogWindow.GetRange( 0, self.LogWindow.GetInsertionPoint() ).split("\n")
lineText = self.LogWindow.GetLineText(lineNum)
```

In thoery that should work...?

[Check This Out...](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/threads/100393)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `PositionToXY()` to find out the line number of a given insertion point, rather than hunting for or counting `\n`s.

```
lineNum = self.LogWindow.PositionToXY(curPos)[1]   # lineNum is the y coord from PosToXY()
```

Comment: In current version as of this comment, wxPython Phoenix TextCtrl.PositionToXY() returns a (bool, x, y) so PositionToXY(curPos)[2] is appropriate.

Comment: Wow - did they change that call?   That seems a bit nasty?

Comment: Yeah. Althought I was using the TextCtrl, I imagine it is likely both wx.LogWindow.PositionToXY() and wx.TextCtrl.PositionToXY() are both inherited from the same place and return a triple instead of a tuple. but I haven't tested it. I'm also doing thing in Python 3.4.2 instead of Python 2.x. There is now some form of overloading used in the Phoenix package although I can't imagine that effecting the return value structure. I did not see any depreciated version (i.e. a backwards compatible) of PositionToXY()